# Debugging test case in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing

How do you debug JUnit test case in Android studio? I placed a breakpoint and used "Debug Test case" but it just runs the code and the breakpoint is ignored.

Update:
This is content of my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.****.mancala"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Same thing for the androidTest of the library project. Legit breakpoints are simply ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the `Run/Debug Configuration` used, the same code with the same breakpoint will stop or not.

- For a configuration with `Test kind: All in package`, the execution
  will not stop at breakpoint
- For a configuration with `Test kind: Class` or `Test kind: Method`, the execution will stop at breakpoint
- For a configuration with `Test kind: All in directory` with `Directory: [myProjectPath]/app/src/test`, the execution will stop at breakpoint

Comment: But why? I am believing that testing All in package is running under a Release setup instead of Debug

Comment: @htafoya That's a good question! I have no clue, and looking at the Android documentation did not help. But when I tried to debug a test (`kind: Class`) while on Active Build Variant release, it stopped on a breakpoint. So I am not sure that release setup is to blame here.

Comment: Well i did some tests and the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is set to `true`, so it must be other configuration of AndroidStudio that disables breakpoints during debug.

Comment: I still don't understand, but I updated the answer with another possibility to get the debugger to actually stop at breakpoints while running tests for more than just one class

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that in your `build.gradle` file (one with all your dependencies) that you have `debuggable true` within the debug build type.

Also just for good measure make sure its a valid breakpoint (not an empty line etc.)

Comment: I put debuggable in debug section, but still not working.